# logging into a website using java?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application. I just started on android development and wanted to know if some how it is possible to log into a website using java. Is there is library or API for achieving something like that?

thanks

Comment: That's extremely vague. Which website? Each website has their own set of APIs or expected requests, if they even make them public. If you want to display a website in your app, use a `WebView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apache httpclient can make web requests.  Using this, you should be able to make your program log into a website.

More information can be found here:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want to connect with remote database and Yes there are Apache Libraries for connecting Database.

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/

Hope this will work for you....Enjoy your Cooked Cake

Comment: I think I will use PHP for connecting to the database (but that is totally for a different purpose) because I think it would a lot faster!